# Skipping to next game level in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

I am in the process of building a game with around 20 levels. Now, as I was thinking of trying to add a "skip" option to the game with the space bar key. I have a little trouble, since holding down the spacebar invokes the **KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN** event multiple times.

The above scenario (Keydown and keyup) works just fine when I'm trying to move my player character on screen.
The one main concern that is lingering in my mind is *"Is this going wrong because the **KeyboardEvent** listeners do get removed and added when changing levels?"*

P.S: Adding the skip option as a button works just fine, but I'd really like to use Spacebar for the ease of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` as well, and keep a boolean that acts as a switch. If the keyboard is pressed AND the boolean is false, set the boolean to true and proceed. Then, when the key_up event callback is invoked, reset the boolean to false.

Comment: I had tried using this said approach. But as I have mentioned in the question, that did not work for me. I think because maybe when a key listener is removed, even if the key up listener is not invoked it gets invoked automatically while cleaning up. I solved this problem by making use of frame count to act as a delay along with the spacebar key press check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does somethig like this work for you?

```
private function levelInit () : {
  // ...
  stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);  
  // ...
}

private function keyDownListener (e : KeyboardEvent) : void {
  if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);
    // add stuff to initiate the level skip
  }
}
```

You could also call the `stage.addEventListener` from a `setTimeout` to delay adding the listener to protect things more.

Comment: I didn't get your point trying to implement a removeEventListener inside a keyDownListener?

Comment: If the flag method that 6NSString outlines doesn't work, then this effectively eliminates the listener from being called repeatedly when a key is held down.  Once you get back to a know state where you can/want to process keystrokes, you can add the listener again.

Comment: Another trick is to disable the down listener in the down listener for all keys (similar to above, but outside the if), and then add it again in an up listener.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the key_down listener in the function and add a key_up listener. Then in the key_up function remove that listener and add back the key_down listener.